# How to convert List of Objects into CSV String using OpenCSV?

Tags: java, opencsv

Following is object:

```
@Data
class Employee{
   private String name;
   private String cubicle;
   private String ssn;
}
```

Want to convert it into CSV using Open CSV:

```
List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<>();
//How to convert list of employee to CSV without using CSV file or reader or writer objects?
```

Not able to find example in http://opencsv.sourceforge.net

Comment: Are you trying to write a file without creating a Writer object? for what? I don't get your point.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17: I want to generate csv contents (String) in one liner and configure bean. instead of using stringbuilders. the string i need to send it further. No writer or files.